# Formatting a file path text in VB for textbox

Tags: vb.net, vba, visual-studio-2008, formatting

Lets say i have 2 buttons "btnBrowse" and "btnImport", i also have a label "lbPath" and a textbox "txtSubject"

When i click browse, the application allows me to look for a file and import the data to a grid view. So i click btnBrowse, find the excel file, double click it, then click btnImport. 4 things happen when i click "btnImport"

1: lbPath.Text changes to the path of the file i picked "C:\Users\me\Desktop\excel.xlsx"
2: The gridview loads the excel file data
3: txtSubject.Text changes to the path of the file as well "C:\Users\me\Desktop\excel.xlsx"
4: the path name becomes the variable "spath" as a string

I would like 1 and 2 to stay the same but for txtSubject.Text, i would like it to grab the last part of the path so the results would be as follows

1: lbPath.Text = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\excel.xlsx"
2: The gridview loads the excel file data
3: txtSubject.Text = "excel.xlsx"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do this:

```
txtSubject.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(lbPath.Text)
```